# Isearch region if active emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to tell isearch to search for the active region, if any?
otherwise prompt for a string regularly.

### Edit: 27.10.12

I ended up using these functions:

```lisp
(defun er/isearch-word-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'isearch-forward-regexp))

(defun er/isearch-yank-word-hook ()
  (when (equal this-command 'er/isearch-word-at-point)
    (let ((string (concat "\\<"
                          (buffer-substring-no-properties
                           (progn (skip-syntax-backward "w_") (point))
                           (progn (skip-syntax-forward "w_") (point)))
                          "\\>")))
      (if (and isearch-case-fold-search
               (eq 'not-yanks search-upper-case))
          (setq string (downcase string)))
      (setq isearch-string string
            isearch-message
            (concat isearch-message
                    (mapconcat 'isearch-text-char-description
                               string ""))
            isearch-yank-flag t)
      (isearch-search-and-update))))

(defun er/isearch-yank-region ()
  (interactive)
  (isearch-yank-internal (lambda () (mark))))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-r") 'er/isearch-yank-region)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-t") 'er/isearch-word-at-point)
```

The first is a function I found somewhere around the web, marking the word under cursor as a search term (similar to * and # in vim) and jumping straight to the next occurance, and the second is @Oleg Pavliv's answer.

### Edit #2

Actually, why not combine them both to get ultra-sweetness? All right!

```lisp
(defun er/isearch-word-or-region-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (isearch-yank-internal (lambda () (mark)))
  (call-interactively 'isearch-forward-regexp)))

(defun er/isearch-yank-word-hook ()
  (when (equal this-command 'er/isearch-word-or-region-at-point)
    (let ((string (concat "\\<"
                          (buffer-substring-no-properties
                           (progn (skip-syntax-backward "w_") (point))
                           (progn (skip-syntax-forward "w_") (point)))
                          "\\>")))
      (if (and isearch-case-fold-search
               (eq 'not-yanks search-upper-case))
          (setq string (downcase string)))
      (setq isearch-string string
            isearch-message
            (concat isearch-message
                    (mapconcat 'isearch-text-char-description
                               string ""))
            isearch-yank-flag t)
      (isearch-search-and-update))))
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook 'er/isearch-yank-word-hook)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-r") 'er/isearch-word-or-region-at-point)
```

Comment: Do you want to limit searching to the region, or do you want the search string to be whatever's in the region?

Comment: Whatever is in the region. I've been trying to play with defadvice, along the lines of "if region is active, yank it into search". Didn't manage so far though:)

Comment: Not sure if you know that selecting a region restricts the search to that region, which in my usage is *far* more useful than using the region as a search term.

Comment: @event_jr - can you give usage examples? I can't remember a time I ever needed such functionality.

Comment: @EladR Usage example for restricting a search to a region?  Hmmm.  Programming.  That's always a good one.  Select a lexical scope and search within that.

Comment: Ah well, when I become a programmer it might be useful. Css, Html and Note-taking (org-mode) doesn't require lexical scope, atm;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

It seems there is no such a possibility in Emacs. You can implement it by yourself

```
(defun isearch-yank-region ()
  (interactive)
  (isearch-yank-internal (lambda () (mark))))


(define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-r" 'isearch-yank-region)
```

Now you select a region, call incremental search `C-s` and yank the region `C-r`. Then you can continue with incremental search `C-s`.

Comment: Perfect. This is excellent, and doesn't conflict with @event_jr usage for search withing region.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve what you want is to save the current region to the kill-ring prior to searching, and then yanking it into the minibuffer as your search term. You can do this by performing the following key sequence:

<kbd>M-w C-s M-y</kbd>

which translates to:

<kbd>M-w</kbd>: saves the region as if killed, but without killing it.

<kbd>C-s</kbd>: do incremental search forward.

<kbd>M-y</kbd>: yank the last string of killed text (or rather, what was saved by <kbd>M-w</kbd> before).

It's a bit of a finger dance to type, but if you use it often enough it will become second nature. The good thing about this generic solution is that it only uses basic functionality that is built into Emacs already. There's no need to advice any functions.

Comment: I like emacs's extendable abilities, but very much dislike its key-bindings. Call it a combination of being lazy and being senile, but I find it rather counter intuitive learning oh-so-many keys to perform actions that should, IMHO, be default.

Comment: @EladR I know what you mean. I pretty much live in Emacs and many key bindings have made it to my muscle memory so I don't have to think about them any more. But even as a die-hard Emacs fan you've got to admit that the key combos can be awkward at times. Luckily, it's so easy to define your own shortcuts. As for my answer, it's fair enough to critize it based on the key bindings (meta, control, meta... geez!), but remember that this sequence was not conceived specifically to do what you ask for. The key bindings just happen to solve your problem, but are otherwise completely generic.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs 28.1 you can use `isearch-forward-thing-at-point`, which is bound to `M-s M-.`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tiny function to use isearch in the following way: if the region is active use it, otherwise just run `isearch-forward`. I hope it may be helpful to someone:

```el
(defun aleksei/isearch-region-or-forward ()
  "Do incremental search forward, use region if it's active"
  (interactive)
  (if (use-region-p)
      (isearch-forward-thing-at-point)
    (isearch-forward)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'aleksei/isearch-region-or-forward)
```